# undefined method '<=' for nil:NilClass Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I have a Ruby model `Book.rb` that has the following:

```
class Book < Library

field :name
field :checked_out, default: false
field :checked_in, default: true

def checked_out?
   checked_out && !checked_in
end

def checked_in?
   checked_in && !checked_out
end
```

Then, in my `index.haml` file, have the following:

```
-@books.each do |book|
   haml :"books/list_all" locals: {book: book}
```

Finally, in my `list_all.haml` file, I have:

```
.h4
   #{book.name}
   - if "#{book.checked_in?}"
      Book is checked in
   - else 
      Book is checked out
```

Update: `book_routes.rb`

```
get '/' do
   haml :'books/index'
end
```

However, I get a  `undefined method <= for nil:NilClass` error. How can I fix this?

Comment: In *this* code? Please include the entire stack trace. Unrelated: A book is not a subclass of a library. Libraries *have* books, books are not libraries.

Comment: How can I get the stack trace? All I see in my terminal is the error I mentioned

Comment: When doing what?

Comment: When I try to navigate `localhost:8080/books` as in my routes I have what I'll update in my code right now

Comment: And there's nothing but that line in the console where you started up the server? Is there a controller? What framework are you using?

Comment: @FlyingCitrus101 you should post the entire log so people can help out. When you are getting errors like while starting server, accessing index page or accessing book show page? If in you your log it's showing nothing related to the book means error is not in this code

Comment: `- if "#{book.checked_in?}"` is one big glowing problem.  `!!"#{false}"` is true as everything except nil and false are truthy in ruby. Remove the string interpolation.

Comment: (And isn't "#{ddd}" doing string interpolation? I barely remember HAML. Do you no longer have to pass locals to partials?)

Comment: I'm using MVC pattern with the `book_routes` in my `controllers` folder and `book.rb` in my `models` folder. I am using Sinatra & besides the normal startup messages on the log, that is the only error message I get when navigating to `localhost:8000/books`

Comment: @DaveNewton It is but I'm unsure what else to do - `- if book.checked_out?` just throws the same `nilClass` error. I know that `book` exists in the iteration because doing `.h4 #{book.name}` prints the book name fine like I mention in my post

Comment: @max See my comment above, if I just do `- if book.checked_in?` I get the `nilClass` error, and if I do `-if #{book.checked_in?}`, it just gets treated as a comment

Comment: Throwing random syntax changes at it won't help :) You might want to see if you need to pass locals to haml templates--you used to have to.

Comment: I have, except if I do #{book.name} it displays the book name for the iteration so I'm not sure why `book` would be nil. It shouldn't have a name if the object is nil right? Also just edited my post with the locals passed in to no avail

Comment: Unrelated, but the `checked_x?` methods don't make a lot of sense--a boolean status requires a single field only.

Comment: Have you sanity-checked the field values in the Ruby code? Is there a controller? It's still unclear to me where this error is appearing or why there's no stack trace--how are you running it?

Comment: I have, yes, and the controller has the routes (`book_routes.rb`). The error appears upon page load of `localhost:8000/books`, when the `list_all.haml` file is launched. I'm using docker but it shouldn't be a docker issue since everything else on my site works fine

Comment: I don't see any meaningful way to help at this point--you need to include the complete flow through the code. Nothing you've shown uses `<=` unless there's something compare-y going on outside of the logical expressions shown (delta annoying Ruby magic) and without a complete overview it's difficult to know what could be happening.

Comment: Also you should ditch the partial and put the code directly into the index file. First rule of debugging is to reduce complexity.

Comment: Hmmm alright I'll try to figure out why the errors are being thrown by going through it a little more and doing some more manual debugging. Appreciate the help!